# Combined form/input selector in one expression

Tags: jquery, forms, class, input, selector

In a huge ajax application I have many forms with individual ids, but the fieldnames may heavily reoccur. Due to differing validation necessities I inevitably need a combined jquery selector consisting of the form name and input class.

To identify validation fields I use classnames like "isadatefield", which are not defined in my css.

What finds too much is:

```
$(".isadatefield").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});}
```

because it finds all input fields with class "isadatefield" in all forms where I only want those in "myform".

Example what should be found:
<form id='myform' ...>
<input id='startdate' name='startdate' class='isadatefield  blue'/>

Example what **NOT** should be found:
<form id='otherform' ...>
<input id='startdate' name='startdate' class='isadatefield  blue'/>

What is the selector for a form named "myform" that addresses all input fields with class "isadatefield" in **only** this form  and avoids addressing other fields named startdate in forms with other ids?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add parent id as a second parameter in the selector

```
$(".isadatefield","#myform").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});}
```

or you can write it this way

```
$("#myform .isadatefield").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});}
```